# How to add divider & Subtitle in drawer in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design

I would like to add Subtitle and divider in navigation drawer like below image screen shot.

[image: Drawer]

I have written below code for navigation drawer but not able to find where i can put Subtitle & divider.

```
drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: const <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Drawer Header',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 24,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.message),
              title: Text('Messages'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
              title: Text('Profile'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
              title: Text('Settings'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

there is a widget for it called `Divider`
you could simply add a Divider as one of the `childrens` of the `ListView`
for the subtitle you could add a `Text` widget and style it to look how you need it to look using a `TextStyle`

```dart
drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: const <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(...),
            Divider(), //here is a divider
            Text("subtitle", style: TextStyle(...)),
            ListTile(...),
            ListTile(...),
            Divider(), //here is a divider
            ListTile(...),
            //rest of your items
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with Divider wigdet https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Divider-class.html

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it as follows:

```
class DividerWithSubheader extends StatelessWidget {
  const DividerWithSubheader({Key? key, required this.subHeader,}) : super(key: key); 
final String subHeader;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Stack(
  children: [
    Divider(),
    Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
      child: Align(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
        child: Text(
          subHeader,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
}}
```

And use it like this:

```
        ListView(children: <Widget>[
          DividerWithSubheader(subHeader: 'subheader Test'),
        ]),
```

Answer (score 2):

Just Provide a `Divider()` within every `ListTile` where you wanna put that thin line on.